# Translation on $x$-operator

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, operators, commutator

I need to show that given $$[x, p_x]=i\hbar$$ the following is true:
$$
e^{iap_x/\hbar}f(x)e^{-iap_x/\hbar}=f(x+a)
$$
for a general function $f(x)$. I've tried using Taylor Series for both exponentials but it only seem to get more complicated and I'm not sure if thats the right approach. Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: If $a$ is a small parameter you can discard terms $\mathcal O(a^2)$ ($a^2$ and higher terms in the expansion).

Comment: Are you familiar with Lagrange's shift operator?

Comment: Not at all, I'll look it up

Comment: Please note that $f(x)$ is a number, so $e^{i a p_x / \hbar} f(x) e^{-iap_x / \hbar}$ is nonsense. It's much better to think as $f$ as the thing you're operating on and write $(e^{i a p_x / \hbar} f e^{-i a p_x / \hbar})(x) = f(x + a)$.

Comment: In some approaches this is the definition of the momentum operator; i.e. the momentum operator is the generator to translations

Comment: @DanielSank In the present context, that doesn't seem to be what OP means. It seems more likely that $f(x)$ is an operator-valued function of the position operator. This calculation makes sense in that context so long as $f$ admits a Taylor expansion. For the OP, you should look up the [Baker-Campbell-Hausdorff formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baker%E2%80%93Campbell%E2%80%93Hausdorff_formula#The_identity).

Comment: @RichardMyers I think the formula written in the question is correct even if $f$ is a function defined $f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$.

Comment: @DanielSank How so? If $f$ is a complex-valued function of some real-valued variable $x$, then $f(x)$ trivially commutes with the exponentials and the result is just $f(x)$, not $f(x+a)$.

Comment: @DanielSank You are implicitly assuming that we are working in the position basis of $p$. But that is simply my statement evaluated in a particular basis. The question makes sense independent of basis only if these objects are operator-valued. Otherwise, as Chris says, $f$ would commute trivially with the exponentials.

Comment: @Chris That's exactly my point. We should *not* write $f(x)$ precisely because $f(x)$ is a number. On the other hand, $f$ is a function and does not commute with the exponentials.

Comment: @RichardMyers Agreed. You can take my recommended form of the equation: $\left( \exp(i a p / \hbar) f \exp(-i a p / \hbar) \right) (x) = f(x + a)$ and just replace the function evaluation parentheses with operator labels to get your recommended form. I do prefer your recommendation, but it's less familiar to a lot of people (because schools mess up peoples' brains by using basis-specific notation).

Comment: @DanielSank This is a pretty standard exercise with $f$ being an operator-valued function of the position operator, though. I see no reason to assume $f$ is a complex-valued function of a real variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The trick is to use the Taylor expansion and the fact that $e^Aa^{-A}=1$:
$$
e^Af(B)e^{-A} = e^A\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}\frac{f^{(n)}(0)B^n}{n!}e^{-A}=
\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}\frac{f^{(n)}(0)\left(e^ABe^{-A}\right)^n}{n!}=
f\left(e^ABe^{-A}\right)
$$

Comment: That was really helpful, using this property and the Prahar Mitra's sugestion below i managed to solve pre problem, thanks for you answer

Answer (score 2):

There's a few different ways to tackle this. One is to expand both $e^{iap_x/\hbar}$ and $f(x)$ as power series and multiply them. This will give you terms like $p_x^nx^m$. Using the canonical commutation relation $[x,p_x]=i\hbar$, you can derive a general expression for $[x^m,p_x^n]$ and use this to commute the $x$ and $p_x$ terms. Then collect like terms and show that

$$ e^{iap_x/\hbar}f(x) = f(x+a)e^{iap_x/\hbar} $$

It might be instructive to work backwards and expand $f(x+a)e^{iap_x/\hbar}$ in terms of power series, so you know what you are working towards.

Comment: Could you go into detail about the general expression for $[x^m, p^n]$? I'm having trouble working it out

Comment: @GustavoSchranckHabermann Hint: $[AB,C]=A[B,C]+[A,C]B$. So $[A^2,B]=A[A,B]+[A,B]A$ and $[x^2,p_x]=2i\hbar x$. You can do something similar for $[x^3,p_x]$ and such until you see the pattern.

Answer (score 0):

First show that
$$
e^{iap_x/\hbar} x e^{-iap_x/\hbar} = x+a
$$
Then, show it for a general function by Taylor expanding $f(x)$ around $x=0$ and then using the property above.

Comment: Unfortunetly i can't accept two answers to the post but your suggestion combined with the previous answer by Vadim solved my problem, Thanks for your suggestions