# Quantum commutation relation $[e^{-x^{2}},e^{\alpha i p}] = ?$

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, operators, commutator

I have been trying for find a closed form solution, or at least something neat for the commutation relation
$$[e^{-x^{2}},e^{\alpha i p}] = ?$$
(where $[x,p] = i\mathbb{I}$)
but have had little luck. I have tried using BHC theorem but this does not get me very far. I think that there must be some simple relation that I am over looking.

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/98372/

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Commutators involving functions](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/98372/)

Comment: Oops I made a mistake. Let me fix the commutator. As it is prior to the changes indeed that post that you shared would suffice.

Comment: @Photon there, this is the commutator I was interested in. I accidentaly wrote down something else.

Comment: Here I have used BCH theorem and them I must compute interations of nested commutators involving the operator $p$. Using the stackexchange post that you shared I end up with a messy series of operators. I was hoping that there would be a nice closed form for the commutator posted above that does not need BCH theorem.

Comment: I see, voted for reopening.

Comment: Thank you @Photon.

Comment: See https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/631995/247642

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have set $\hbar=1$, so $p= -i\partial_x$ in the coordinate representation, so one of your operators is a bland Lagrange [shift operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shift_operator), and hence
$$
[e^{\alpha i p},  f(x)  ] = (f(x+\alpha)-f(x)) e^{\alpha i p}    ~~~~\leadsto \\
 [e^{-x^2}, e^{\alpha i p}]= - (e^{-(x+\alpha)^2}-e^{x^2}) e^{\alpha i p}  .
$$

(With a tip of the hat to @thedude 's comment! The linked WP article reminds you that $e^{i\alpha p} f(x) e^{-i\alpha p}= f(x+\alpha) $, in [operator calculus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baker%E2%80%93Campbell%E2%80%93Hausdorff_formula#An_important_lemma_and_its_application_to_a_special_case_of_the_Baker%E2%80%93Campbell%E2%80%93Hausdorff_formula) language; when it acts on a constant, it reduces to just  $e^{i\alpha p} f(x)= f(x+\alpha) $.)

Make sure to confirm for small *α*.

Comment: This is phenomenal !!! Thank you very much!

Comment: Actually $[e^{\alpha ip},f(x)]g(x)=e^{\alpha ip}f(x)g(x)-f(x)e^{\alpha ip}g(x)$, so this answer is in the right direction but not correct

Comment: Do you know where I might find a proof of these wonderful result. i.e. $[e^{\alpha i p},f(x)] = f(x+\alpha)$ where $x$ and $p$ are the position and momentum operators respectively.

Comment: After the edit, this is now correct

Comment: Fantastic! I appreciate all of your comments and help. Special thanks to @CosmasZachos

Comment: The answer is now correct. Your last comment is correct only if you look at $e^{i \alpha p}f(x)$ as an operator.  But if the operator is $e^{i \alpha p}$ it transforms the function $f(x)$ in the function $f(x+a)$. In any case, the final results can be obtained independently of this alternative views.

Comment: @GiorgioP yes, of course. I edited the question to accommodate action on a translationally invariant state such as the vacuum. The combinatoric derivation is the standard matrix exponential derivation, but I thought Lagrange's argument is self-evident for those who have not encountered it.